# Adding a footer only to the last page when using cfdocument

Tags: coldfusion, footer, cfdocument

I'm creating a multipage document using `cfdocument` (created using dynamic text so could have any number of pages even one).

I can use `<cfdocumentitem type="footer">` to add a footer to every page, but is there any way I can only add a footer to just the last page of the document?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just add the evalAtPrint attribute. Then you can use the page number variables to conditionally set the footer.

```
<cfdocumentitem type="footer" evalAtPrint="true">
    <cfif cfdocument.currentPageNumber eq cfdocument.totalPageCount>
        This is the last page
    </cfif>
</cfdocumentitem>
```

Comment: Although it's not listed in the [documentation for cfdocumentitem in CF8](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_d-e_06.html#3980064), it does work.

Comment: @Jon - Yes, you are right. The CF9 documentation says it was added in CF8, but I feel like it was 8.0.1. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7758.html